# C# Output Console - "System.Collection.Generic.Dictionary2+ValueCollection" Kinect v2

Tags: c#, console, output, kinect-sdk

I am new in c# and i have a problem with console output.
I have include using System and using System.IO 
But when i print something in console output i don't see nothing.
If i write:

```
`Console.WriteLine("AAAAAAA");`
```

But I don't see AAAAAAAA... why?

I am in kinect FaceBasic code:
And i want print a variable. (the FaceFrameResults values)

The variable is FaceFrameResult.FacePointsInInfraredSpace Property.

```
Type: IReadOnlyDictionary<FacePointType, Point>
```

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh136548.aspx)

I want to print this with this code:

`Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}",faceFrame.FaceFrameResult.FacePointsInColorSpace.Keys,faceFrame.FaceFrameResult.FacePointsInColorSpace.Values);`

But nothing happens, and does not give me any errors or warnings.
If i try to print the value using messagebox

```
`MessageBox.Show(faceFrameResults[index].FacePointsInInfraredSpace.Values.ToString());`
`MessageBox.Show(faceFrameResults[index].FacePointsInInfraredSpace.Values);`
```

I obtain this:

*System.Collection.Generic.Dictionary'2+ValueCollection[Microsoft.Kinect.Face.FacePointType.Microsoft.Kinect.PointF]*

Which is the problem?
Thank you in advance for your reply!

Comment: You can't print out the values and keys all at once, you need to iterate over the collection and print them out one at a time.

Comment: but even if I write only values: "MessageBox.Show(faceFrame.FaceFrameResult.FacePointsInColorSpace.Values.ToString()); " i have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to print out a collection, you can't do this directly, you need to iterate over the collection and print out each item one by one. e.g.

```
foreach(var kvp in faceFrame.FaceFrameResult.FacePointsInColorSpace)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

Comment: It's work! thank you! sorry but I have not yet practicality with foreach.
(I print a message with messagebox, becouse with console.writeline i don't see anything. why?)
The problem is that the key is right but in value i see: Microsoft.Kinect.PointF